How do I walk a directory recursively while following links in PHP?
Of course, I've tried the obvious:
<?php
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator (new RecursiveDirectoryIterator ('.'), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $x)
{
    echo $x->getPathname (), "\n";
}
?>

...Which happens to be the selected answer here. but the problem, of course, is that it doesn't follow links, even though I've configured Apache (my chosen web server) to allow following of links. The links all work, except for this - so far as I am aware.
Here are the results (and yes, I'm in the editor as I run this development code):
./index.php ./. ./.index.php.swp ./..

I'd hate to have to resort to calling an external program for this; is there another (simpler / more efficient) way and if so, what is it?
The links are "soft", as in:
$ ln -s /some/file/path

The Apache directives for directories have this option, which has been used:
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks


Progress But Not Success
Prompted by Chris' comment below, I updated the code and it's BETTER but still not working fully.
To test, I have this tree - "top" is a soft link:
top
├── Fashionista
│   ├── GogoBoots_1.jpg
│   ├── OurFeet_1.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_1.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_2.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_3.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_4.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_5_better_lighting.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_6.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_7_fav.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_dark_1.jpg
│   ├── You_n_Me_too_dark_1.jpg
│   └── You_n_Me_too_dark_2.jpg
├── ReadMe
└── UnreleasedFilm
    ├── Joes_Mythos_I.iso
    └── Nancys_Reviews.mbox

3 directories, 15 files

The code to look at this (which will eventually toss up images when the entry is an image and so forth), here's the present code and its output:
<?php

$ade = new RecursiveIteratorIterator (
         new RecursiveDirectoryIterator ($directory),
         RecursiveDirectoryIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS |
         RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST |
         RecursiveDirectoryIterator::UNIX_PATHS);
$ade->rewind();

foreach ($ade as $entry)
{
   $basename = $entry->getBasename();
   $pathWithFilename = $entry->getPathname();
   $isLink = $entry->isLink();
   $isDir = $entry->isDir();
   if ($basename !== "." && $basename !== "..")
   {
      say("Basename: $basename");
      say("Path:     $pathWithFilename");
      say("isLink:   $isLink");
      say("isDir:    $isDir");
   } else {
      say("Dots!");
   }
   // say() just adds <br> at the end of an echo
}
?>

And here are the results:
Dots!
Dots!
Basename: UnreleasedFilm
Path: top/UnreleasedFilm
isLink:
isDir: 1
Basename: Fashionista
Path: top/Fashionista
isLink:
isDir: 1
Basename: JustAFile.txt
Path: top/JustAFile.txt
isLink:
isDir: 

As you can see, it is not walking the tree, it's ONLY going a single level. I need it to walk the whole tree.
I figured tree walking was what RecursiveIteratorIterator and / or RecursiveDirectoryIterator is / are about?
I figure I'm doing it wrong!
As an aside, I tried adding this in the new RecursiveDirectoryIterator section and it didn't work either:
//         RecursiveIteratorIterator::SKIP_DOTS |


"it doesn't follow links" - I'm not clear why you mean, are these symbolic (hard/soft) links? Or are you talking about hyperlinks? I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

@ChrisHaas  Soft links...  I haven't the slightest idea how "hyperlinks" - I take it you mean URLs? - could be involved here? We're talking about file-system lookups.  But since you got an upvote on that comment I'll update the Q!

yeah, sorry, just had to ask, sometimes you just don’t know. And because you mentioned Apache, I just wasn’t sure. Regardless, I don’t think Apache’s configuration should affect PHP’s. Have you tried FOLLOW_SYMLINKS?

@ChrisHaas Why NO, Chris, I'm new to PHP - only started with it a few weeks ago - and part-time at that... Care to make an answer out of that?! I'm still 2 to 3 hours from starting work this morning - just checked in over coffee! - but will dig in as soon as I'm able.

I'm going to defer to you for an answer since you are actively debugging this. I haven't used the recursive file system functions in a long while unfortunately.

@ChrisHaas Thanks for letting me know; I've given up on the claim of built-in recursion for now since after a couple of hours I didn't find a solution and  I'm such a newbie with this. I DO know how to do recursion the old-fashioned way! ...I'll hold off on posting my non-answer for now...

Honestly, I avoid a lot of things that are part of SPL such as this. Not because they are bad, they're just complicated to get right sometimes. If you can do this with plain boring recursion, I would 100% recommend just doing that. Back when SPL was introduced there might have been some performance gains for file system things, but I don't think you'll see much, if any, these days. I still like SplFileInfo itself, however, for an OOP description of a file.
